# Can I use multiple queries inside SELECT EXISTS()?

Tags: sql, pdo

Is it possible to write multiple queries inside the SQL `EXISTS()`?

Just as this example

```
SELECT 
    EXISTS (SELECT a FROM at WHERE X = :X;
            SELECT b FROM bt WHERE Y = :Y;
            SELECT C FROM ct WHERE Z = :Z;
           )
```

And in case it is possible, is this the best way to check the existence of an element inside multiple tables? or using `UNION ALL` or `JOIN` would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
EXISTS (SELECT a FROM at WHERE X = :X) OR
EXISTS (SELECT b FROM bt WHERE Y = :Y) OR
EXISTS (SELECT C FROM ct WHERE Z = :Z)
```

This would normally be in a `WHERE` or `CASE`, not a `SELECT`.

You can use `UNION ALL`, but this is usually more efficient.

Comment: I guess `AND` Would be better to assure that all `EXISTS`, And as i understood `SELECT EXISTS() OR|AND EXISTS() . . .` is the way to use multiple queries.